# GUI Apps without a graphical desktop

Tags: linux, fedora, desktop

This may be a stupid question - But is it possible to run GUI apps (Firefox for example) on a computer where I don't have a graphical desktop installed (like GNOME, Xfce)?

Comment: Are you simply asking out of curiosity or do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Just curious. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install X windows without installing a desktop, and run apps under bare X. It's a bit strange like that: no background, no window borders. Or you can add a minimal window manager.

[Can I have Graphics on Linux without a desktop manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/493319/can-i-have-graphics-on-linux-without-a-desktop-manager?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. There are couple of options (which you want is not clear from question).

1. Some programs can be run in headless mode where they accept the situation where X-server is not available
2. You only need X-server running at client computer, it is not necessary at the server running the software. For example, if Firefox is installed in server you use ssh to connect to you can use `ssh -X` to connect and run firefox at the server => firefox UI is drawn to your computer.

Comment: So for example, would firefox look/behave the same even though it doesn't have X to run off of?

Comment: In short, yes. Settings, history and other stuff (if not synced otherwise) would of course be from machine executing firefox, not from one displaying the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Here  are several headless X servers some of them are:

- virtual x server: xpra,
- nested: xnest, xserver-xephyr

Also, you  can run xorg with dummy display driver.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old post if anyone is searching for this use this:

install xorg first

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
```

if you dont already have install xterm

```
sudo apt install xterm
```

this is the command to run it in the same window or console

```
xinit firefox $* -- :0 vt$XDG_VTNR
```

use this to run on a different display

```
sudo xinit firefox $* -- :1
```

where 1 is display 1.